# Wpf control triggers collection clears after setting control background

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, code-behind

I have a simple trigger for button:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E6DB6"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

This works nice, until i set button's background in code-behind:

```
neighborButton.Background = notClickedButtonBackground;
```

After this `neighborButton.Triggers` collection becomes empty and the functionality is lost.
Why the cause of that behavior?

Comment: ["Local values" override Style trigger setters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265148(v=vs.95).aspx). You'd get the same effect if you set the background color in an attribute on the Button element in XAML. The answer is to use code behind, or add properties to expose the logic and do it in triggers, but don't try to mix the two. When you fight the framework, the framework usually gets the last laugh.

Comment: Thanks Ed, not it's clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency properties are much more complicated than regular C# properties. What you're doing is setting a ["Local value", which will override Style trigger setters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265148(v=vs.95).aspx) You'd get the same effect if you set the `Background` brush in an attribute on the `Button` element in XAML (but you'd get it as the initial state of the control, and you'd be here asking why your trigger doesn't work at all). The answer is to do it all code behind, or add properties to expose the logic and do it in triggers, but don't try to mix the two. When you fight the framework, the framework usually gets the last laugh. My frontal assaults on the framework have been [Pyrrhic victories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory) at best, and [more often debacles](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/health_and_science/pandemics/2012/12/121210_PAN_Napoleon1812.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg).

I don't recommend doing it in code behind, but if you've already got a bunch of time invested you may as well stick with that for this project. However, that means you lose your mouseover colors. You'd be nuts to try to do that in code behind.

It's worth taking a look at the MSDN pages for [`DependencyObject.GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DependencyObject.ReadLocalValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.readlocalvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), both of which I'm using below.

I can't reproduce your behavior with the disappearing triggers. I still have one trigger even after setting the background in the event handler. It just has no effect.

XAML:

```
<Button 
    Click="Button_Click"
    Content="Click Me"
    >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E6DB6" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    var triggers = btn.Style.Triggers;

    //  GetValue returns the "effective value": Maybe local, maybe not;
    //  whatever it is, it's the value that will be used. 
    var background = btn.GetValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);

    //  If there's a local value, it overrides whatever else has been set.
    //  Note that a value set by a template trigger on a property of an 
    //  element within the template is a local value. 
    var localbackground = btn.ReadLocalValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);

    //  Right now, 
    //      background == #FF3E6DB6
    //      localbackground == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

    btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen);

    background = btn.GetValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
    localbackground = btn.ReadLocalValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);

    //  Now they're both #FF9ACD32, which is YellowGreen
    //  triggers.Count == 1

    btn.Content = $"Trigger count: {triggers?.Count}";
}
```